# I wanna have some unique selling points on my productpages

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

How is it possible to add some unique selling points to my productpages.
I was thinking about making a block or something?

Hope you guys can help me out.

Comment: What type of selling points you want? Explain more.

Comment: Like this: https://ibb.co/mAwWZJ. so it has to be text/bullitpoints

Comment: Does these values are coming from product attribute or you need to use dynamic calculations?

Comment: No i just want static content, so it will be something like:

- Free shipping
- Always the newest fashion
- On friday we eat pancakes
- And more to like this

Comment: So this content will not be changed product wise?

Comment: Nope, it will be the same on each productpage.

Answer (score 0):

In `app\code\Namespace\Modulename\view\frontend\layout\catalog_product_view.xml` add like below code. You can use your required `referenceContainer`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="alert.urls">
        <block class="Namespace\Modulename\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Module" name="textblock" as="textblock" after="-" template="catalog/product/view/textblock.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

Comment: Mag je hier in het Nederlands vragen stellen of is dat verboden?

Comment: @Joost Hmm no idea to be honest ^^'

Comment: or is it oke that i send ya a PM?

Comment: @Joost sure not sure if that is possible here though.

Comment: Ik zie nergens de mogelijkheid om een PM te sturen. Helaas.
Zoals ik het lees, plaats ik bovenstaande code in de de xml? En welk stukje laat ik linken aan mijn staticblock? Waar kan ik dat invoeren? Dat stukje begrijp ik niet helemaal.

Answer (score 0):

Create a static block and paste the content which you want to show on product details page with some identifier and then create catalog_product_view.xml on your module and add the following code:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
        <container name="product-page-static" label="Product Page Static Block" as="product-page-static-block" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-info-static" before="product.info">
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="Staticblock">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">your_static_block_identifier</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </container>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

Also replace the your_static_block_identifier with yours. Location of your catalog_product_view.xml will be:

> app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml